# How to create specific table from array using JS/JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table

I'm working on some project and im stuck with this for a while. I have table like this in database:

| ProjectName | UserName | SpentDays |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FirstProject | User1 | 10 |
| SecondProject | User1 | 5 |
| SecondProject | User2 | 3 |
| ThirdProject | NULL | NULL |

Then i get that informations in js in array like this:

```js
ProjectInfo = [{
  ProjectName: 'FirstProject',
  UserName: 'User1',
  SpentDays: 10
}, {
  ProjectName: 'SecondProject',
  UserName: 'User1',
  SpentDays: 5
}, {
  ProjectName: 'SecondProject',
  UserName: 'User2',
  SpentDays: 3
}, {
  ProjectName: 'ThirdProject',
  UserName: NULL,
  SpentDays: NULL
}]
```

How can i get HTML table like this using JS/JQUERY:

| Projects | User1 | User2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FirstProject | 10 | NULL |
| SecondProject | 5 | 3 |
| ThirdProject | NULL | NULL |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a mix of reduce and map and template literals

```js
const NULL = null; // or you use null in the object
ProjectInfo = [{
  ProjectName: 'FirstProject',
  UserName: 'User1',
  SpentDays: 10
}, {
  ProjectName: 'SecondProject',
  UserName: 'User1',
  SpentDays: 5
}, {
  ProjectName: 'SecondProject',
  UserName: 'User2',
  SpentDays: 3
}, {
  ProjectName: 'ThirdProject',
  UserName: NULL,
  SpentDays: NULL
}]

const users = [...new Set(ProjectInfo.map(({ UserName }) => UserName))].filter(user => user != NULL); // create a list of users
document.querySelector("table thead tr").innerHTML += users.map(user => `<th>${user}</th>`).join(""); // add them to the table head

// create a default object
const obj = JSON.stringify(users.reduce((acc, user) => {
  acc[user] = "NULL";
  return acc
}, {}));

// reduce to something more manageable 
const rows = ProjectInfo.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.ProjectName] = acc[cur.ProjectName] || JSON.parse(obj)
  if (cur.UserName !== null) acc[cur.ProjectName][cur.UserName] = cur.SpentDays
  return acc
}, {});

document.querySelector("table tbody").innerHTML = Object
  .entries(rows)
  .map(([name,project]) => `<tr><td>${name}</td>${Object
    .values(project)
    .map(val => `<td>${val}</td>`)
    .join("")}</tr>`)
  .join("");
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css" />
<table class="s-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Projects</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick.

Nevermind this answer, I misread what the OP was wanting.

```js
projectInfo = [{
  ProjectName: 'FirstProject',
  UserName: 'User1',
  SpentDays: 10
}, {
  ProjectName: 'SecondProject',
  UserName: 'User1',
  SpentDays: 5
}, {
  ProjectName: 'SecondProject',
  UserName: 'User2',
  SpentDays: 3
}, {
  ProjectName: 'ThirdProject',
  UserName: null,
  SpentDays: null
}];

var tbody = $('#mytable tbody');

projectInfo.forEach(e => {
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
  row.append($("<td></td>").text(e.ProjectName));
  row.append($("<td></td>").text(e.UserName));
  row.append($("<td></td>").text(e.SpentDays));
  tbody.append(row);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" border=1>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Projects</th>
    <th>UserName</th>
    <th>SpentDays</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```